# Disable BinLogging for particular table, where to execute parameter change

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqlbinlog

To disable bin logging for a given table I understand I can use this command:

replicate-ignore-table=db_name.tbl_name

However I am unsure where I need to execute it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add it to the configuration file (my.cfg) and restart MySQL.

This however is a `SLAVE` option, meaning that it should be in the config on the slave servers, and it tells them to ignore the updates to a particular table. It does not disable binary logging for that table, and other slaves can proceed the statements.

Comment: Very quick follow up, the above statement replicate-ignore-table=db.table should disable bin logging ala carte for each table I add right?

Comment: @JohnWoods actually this is a `slave` option, it should be on the slave config and the slave will ignore the replication for this table. [You can't ignore table from binary logging](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30660/mysql-binary-logs-skip-a-table), only entire db

Comment: Updated answer. @John Woods